# How to display the result of another controller action without using RedirectToAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two ASP.NET MVC controller actions as included below and would like `RenderComponent` to display the contents of `RenderComponentPublic` without calling `RedirectToAction`.

Instead, I would like the content to be revealed under `RenderComponent` and for no redirect to take place.

Could anybody suggest a way to achieve this?

**Controller Action 1 - `RenderComponent`**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
public ActionResult RenderComponent(
  string ckey,
  string ukey)
  {
        return RedirectToAction("RenderComponentPublic", new
                {
                    ckey,
                    ukey
        });
  }
```

**Controller Action 2 - `RenderComponentPublic`**

```
public ActionResult RenderComponentPublic(
  string ckey,
  string ukey)
  {
      return PartialView("_ThisContent");
  }
```

Comment: So you want the content of both? E.g. return `RenderComponent` and display `RenderComponentPublic` also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always call the other action within C#.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "user")]
public ActionResult RenderComponent(
  string ckey,
  string ukey)
  {
        return RenderComponentPublic(ckey,ukey);
  }
```

Comment: Calling the action directly is probably the easiest way. Thanks Steven.

Comment: if RenderComponentPublic is in another controller?

Comment: @JuanCarlosVelez You could create an instance of the other controller, and then call the action like `new OtherController().RenderComponentPublic()`. But that could have unintended side effects since not all the HTTP request information is passed into the new context. But, if you want a more detailed answer, you may want to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with your specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

One way that might suit your needs is to call `Html.RenderAction` So within your `RenderComponent` view, just call;

```
@(Html.RenderAction("RenderComonentPublic", new { ckey = Model.ckey, ukey = Model.ukey });)
```

or

```
@Html.Action("RenderComonentPublic", new { ckey = Model.ckey, ukey = Model.ukey })
```

You would have to pass your `ckey` and `ukey` into the view within the Model, or a ViewBag or something.

Your `RenderComponentPublic` view would need to have it's `layout` page set to `null` in order for it not be be rendered within a layout.

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Tim. RenderComonentPublic doesn't have an associated view so I'd need to use Steven's approach. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I notice that it is just returning the partial view, why not just `@Html.Partial("_ThisContent")` ?